# Dependency/Assembly/Build Management C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, build

In my solution, there are two projects A and B. 
Project A references some external DLLs. 
Project A references Project B. 
It compiles well, but i get runtime exceptions because there are some assemblies missing.

Do i have to add all references from project B in project A again?
What happens to the Dependency Bindings used in app.config of project A?
Or simply: What are best practices to get a clean build management in .net?

In java i was using maven to solve this issues.

[image: Sample Solution]

Comment: Yes, you still need to have those references in project B.

Comment: Do I also need the references needed at compile time of project A in project B or only the one, needed at run time?

Comment: Ok, I think things are getting a bit mixed up here and I may have misunderstood your original question. Let us say that Project A references r1, r2, and r3 and Project B references Project A. Project B will NOT need to reference r1, r2, and r3 as long as they are only used in Project A. If any of those libraries are used in Project B, then they will need to be referenced there as well. At compile time, if Project B is only referencing Project A, then it will only need Project A to compile. At runtime, when Project A is called from Project B, references r1, r2, and r3 will need to be available.